# d3 nested grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

First of all sorry if my English is difficult to understand, I'll try my best...

I am rather new to D3.js and I'm trying to create a D3 grouped bar chart using nested data. I have looked at some solutions shared here, but they only show one-level grouping. In my case,  data will come from a csv file that has this data structure:

```
groups,categories,value 1,value 2,value 3
group 1,A,61.0158803,25.903359,13.08076071
group 1,B,71.27703826,21.0180133,7.70494844
group 1,C,82.70203982,13.52731445,3.770645737
group 2,A,58.85721523,28.25939061,12.88339417
group 2,B,71.39695487,20.66010982,7.942935308
group 2,C,82.22389321,13.68924542,4.08686137
```

The chart is intended to have two x axis, one for the groups (level 0) and one for the categories (level 1).Values 1 to 3 will display as grouped bars for each catergory, and the categories will be displayed within the corresponding group.

The structure of the chart should be:

```
value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 |
|        category A         |          category B         |          category C         |
|                                       group 1                                         |
```

and the same for group 2, placed contiguous.

The problem is with the code I am working on, I get the right axis but data corresponding two both groups are shown, one on top of the other, in each group area. I am not able to link the data on the categories to their corresponding group in orther to draw them where it corresponds.

Here is the code I've got so far:

```
var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0,width], 0);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0,width]);

var x2 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height,0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var x0Axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom");

var x1Axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x1)
 .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select(".chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "svg")
  .attr("viewBox", "" + margin* -1 + " " + margin* -1 + " " + (width + margin*2) + " " + (height + margin *2) + "")
  .attr ("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")



d3.csv("../data/EQ01.csv", function(error, data){
  if (error) throw error;

 var seriesNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "categories" && key !== "groups";});

  data.forEach(function(d) {
 d.values = seriesNames.map(function(name) { return {
     xValue: name,
     yValue: +d[name]
   };
 });
   });

   nested = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.groups})
      .key(function(d) { return d.categories})
      .entries(data);

  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function(d) { return d.yValue; }); })]);
  x0.domain(nested.map(function(d) {return d.key;}));
  x1.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.categories; })).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand() ], 0.1);
  x2.domain(seriesNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x1.rangeBand()], 0);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x0 axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height+30) + ")")
    .call(x0Axis);

  svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .call(yAxis)

  var group = svg.selectAll(".group")
   .data(nested)
   .enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "group")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.key) + ",0)"; });

  group.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x1 axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(x1Axis);

  var category = group.selectAll(".category")
   .data(data)
   .enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "category")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x1(d.categories) + ",0)"; });

  category.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x2.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x2(d.xValue); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.yValue); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.yValue); })
  .style("fill", function(d){return color(d.xValue)})
```

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I think it should be `.data(function(d) { return d.values; })` for the `'.category'` groups. If this doesn't work, can you set-up a jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: Hi @tarulen, and thanks for the answer! I have tried that and it doesn't seem to work. Here is a JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hLaxmb8p/3/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you are not joining correctly your data with your elements.

We need to build different scales in order to obtain the correct `rangeBand` value.

```
var x_groups = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x_categories = d3.scale.ordinal();

var x_values = d3.scale.ordinal();
```

I created a nested data structure that will contain everything we need for our grouped bar chart approach.

```
var nested = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.groups;
    })
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.categories;
    })
    .rollup(function(leaves) {
      return [{
        key: 'v-a',
        value: leaves[0]['value 1']
      }, {
        key: 'v-b',
        value: leaves[0]['value 2']
      }, {
        key: 'v-c',
        value: leaves[0]['value 3']
      }];
    })
    .entries(data);
```

Next lets configure our scales with the information we just got.

```
  x_groups.domain(nested.map(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  }));
  //var categories = ['A', 'B', 'C']; 
  var categories = nested[0].values.map(function(d, i) {
    return d.key;
  });
  x_categories.domain(categories).rangeRoundBands([0, x_groups.rangeBand()]);
  //var values = ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3']; 
  var values = nested[0].values[0].values.map(function(d, i) {
    return d.key;
  });
  x_values.domain(values).rangeRoundBands([0, x_categories.rangeBand()]);
```

Then we can finally start our data join. You can see that when we enter a new level of info we need to set the `data` function correctly.

```
var groups_g = svg.selectAll(".group")
  .data(nested)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'group group-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x_groups(d.key) + ",0)";
  });

var categories_g = groups_g.selectAll(".category")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'category category-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x_categories(d.key) + ",0)";
  });

var categories_labels = categories_g.selectAll('.category-label')
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d.key];
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'category-label category-label-' + d;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x_categories.rangeBand() / 2;
  })
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return height + 25;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })

var values_g = categories_g.selectAll(".value")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'value value-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x_values(d.key) + ",0)";
  });

var values_labels = values_g.selectAll('.value-label')
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d.key];
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'value-label value-label-' + d;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x_values.rangeBand() / 2;
  })
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return height + 10;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })

var rects = values_g.selectAll('.rect')
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d];
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "rect")
  .attr("width", x_values.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return 0;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.key);
  });
```

Working plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/qGZ1YuyFZnVtp04bqZki?p=preview

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot @torresomar !! It worked perfectly and most of all, I have learned a lot fromm your answer!!