# d3 based multiple sub groups of a bar chart

Tags: d3.js, grouping, bar-chart, hierarchical-data, dc.js

I am trying to produce a bar graph that has multiple hierarchical / groupings of factors using `d3.js`. An example from excel of what I am attempting to create, subgrouped by Variety and Irrigation treatment:

[image]

I have searched for quite some time and have yet to see an example of something like the example graph above. The closet I found is [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) (as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889019/d3-js-grouped-bar-chart), [this](http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBar.html), and [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967)).

but they all lack the one more level of grouping that I need.

Is there a way to create multiple groupings in `d3.js`, or **any other reusable charts** based on d3.js, like [dc.js](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/)?
If so, a demo chart is appreciated. You can use [this csv data](https://gist.github.com/suntong/bf7c82ed8ed7ff20eff71e1b1dede1e9).
Chart Population1, Population2 etc for each countries, and group them by Continent.

**UPDATE:**

@Gordon, thanks for your reply and links. One thing though, are you sure the pull request is about *multiple* *sub* groups? From the posted pictures in the thread, it looks like just normal grouping to me:

[image]

which is already available in d3, e.g.,

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/882152

Thanks for any help you may have!

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690018/d3-nested-grouped-bar-chart) has a plunker that may help you.

Comment: @snolflake, indeed, that helped. However, anybody knows how to move the `v-a`, `v-b`, `v-c` etc from the axis to the legend? Basically that code works, but not reusable (look at the hard-coded  `v-a`, `v-b`, `v-c` etc in the js code). I'm not a JavaScript developer to understand and adapt the code myself, so I'm seeking a reusable solution (e.g., work for any number of Population columns). Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you're interested in a dc.js solution, there's [this pull request](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1043) which looks pretty good and will hopefully be merged soon.  And [this issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1191) links to a fiddle demonstrating how to add error bars (less likely to become a core feature).