# Chartjs 2: Multi level/hierarchical category axis in chartjs

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

Is it possible to define a bar chart with a multi level/category axis?

For instance I'd like to display the Region/Province categories like in this Excel chart: 
[image]

I found [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hamalainen/6c0L1yva/3/) example using multiple xAxes.

```
xAxes:[
    {
      id:'xAxis1',
      type:"category",
      ticks:{
        callback:function(label){
          var month = label.split(";")[0];
          var year = label.split(";")[1];
          return month;
        }
      }
    },
    {
      id:'xAxis2',
      type:"category",
      gridLines: {
        drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
      },
      ticks:{
        callback:function(label){
          var month = label.split(";")[0];
          var year = label.split(";")[1];
          if(month === "February"){
            return year;
          }else{
            return "";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

The problem is it seems that the two axes are not really linked and the alignment of second axis is based on values instead of aligning in middle of lower level category. this case cause issues

Is there a clean way to achieve this in chart.js?

**Update:**
I ended up creating a [feature request](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4946) on chartjs.

Comment: are looking for a charts.js solution only?

Comment: I'm currently evaluating several chart libraries but I'd like to know if it's doable in chartjs in particular.

Comment: I think this is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180871/grouped-bar-charts-in-chart-js

Comment: Not it's not the same. I'm looking for hierarchical categories in combination with grouped bar chart. Please look closely at the category axis in my example chart.

Comment: @Sebastien I would like to know how you resolve it (if you did), even with other Chart library. thanks!

Comment: @danelgi We are using Echarts now. And using a custom Serie

Comment: Duplicate question, same question asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934608/how-to-create-two-x-axes-label-using-chart-js/42934853#42934853

Comment: hi @Sebastien, did you get the expected output for this problem??

Answer (score 1):

you can provide value separately for different axis via `datesets` and provide an object with different configuration option `(borderColor, pointBackgroundColor, pointBorderColor)` etc, i hope It'll help.

here is the link for the with an update (fiddle you shared) [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6qsfkkn6/)

```
data: {
labels: ["January;2015", "February;2015", "March;2015", "January;2016", "February;2016", "March;2016"],
datasets: [{
  label: '# of Votes',
  xAxisID:'xAxis1',
  data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
},

// here i added another data sets for xAxisID 2 and it works just fine
{
  label: '# of Potatoes',
  xAxisID:'xAxis2',
  data: [9, 17, 28, 26, 29, 9]
}]
```

}

I hope that solves your problem :)

Comment: My problem is not having multiple data sets. My problem is displaying an axis with hierarchical categories. The JsFiddle try to achieve this using a secondary axis with some empty labels but this ends up having some alignment issues that are not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

I did a bit of research and couldn't find methods to implement your solution in chartjs.  Chartjs has grouped bar charts but not subgrouped bar charts like in your case.

```
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/harshakj89/ax3zxtzw/
```

**Here are some alternatives,**

D3js (https://d3js.org/) can be used to create sub grouped bar charts.Data can be loaded from csv or json. D3 is highly configurable, but you may have to put some effort than chartsjs.

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/qGZ1YuyFZnVtp04bqZki?p=preview
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690018/d3-nested-grouped-bar-chart
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764698/loading-d3-js-data-from-a-simple-json-string
```

ZingChart is a commercial tool and can be used to implement bar charts with sub groupes.

https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/bar-charts/

But I prefer D3 over this library. because D3 comes under BSD License.

Comment: As stated in my previous comment. I'm currently evaluating several chart libraries but I'd like to know if it's doable in chartjs in particular.

Comment: @Sebastien i don't think it's doable.

Comment: @Sebastien Yes it's **doable** in chart.js, but that's not an easy job. I don't think anyone's gonna do it for ya w/o actual $$.

Comment: So if I I understand your question correctly it does not work out of the box or as plugin right?

Comment: You will have a better chance with D3 js.

Answer (score 0):

The best library I could found to have exactly this feature is [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo), this is my implementation:
[image]
and here http://jsfiddle.net/fieldsure/Lr5sjh5x/2/ you can find out how to implement it.

```js
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: "container",
            type: "column",
            borderWidth: 5,
            borderColor: '#e8eaeb',
            borderRadius: 0,
            backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7'
        },
        title: {
            style: {
                'fontSize': '1em'
            },
            useHTML: true,
            x: -27,
            y: 8,
            text: '<span class="chart-title"> Grouped Categories with 2 Series<span class="chart-href"> <a href="http://www.blacklabel.pl/highcharts" target="_blank"> Black Label </a> </span> <span class="chart-subtitle">plugin by </span></span>'
        },
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '${value}',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Daily Tickets',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Invoices',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '${value}',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }]
        ,
        series: [{
            name: 'Daily',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mm'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Invoices',
            type: 'column',
            data: [4, 17, 18, 8, 9, 5, 13, 15, 18],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' °C'
            }
        }],
        xAxis: {
            categories: [{
                name: "1/1/2014",
                categories: ["Vendor 1", "Vendor 2", "Vendor 3"]
            }, {
                name: "1/2/2014",
                categories: ["Vendor 1", "Vendor 2", "Vendor 3"]
            }, {
                name: "1/3/2014",
                categories: ["Vendor 1", "Vendor 2", "Vendor 3"]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/grouped-categories.js"></script>

<div id="container" class="chart-container"></div>
```

But the problem is the library is not free for commercial purposes, and this is the [Chartjs implementation](https://github.com/datavisyn/chartjs-scale-hierarchical/issues/4), in my case it is look like this:

```js
const data ={"labels":[{"label":"Exams","children":["Wellness Examination"]},{"label":"Surgery","children":["Neuter Surgery"]},{"label":"Vaccines","children":["Bordetella"]},{"label":"Dentistry","children":["Dental Cleaning"]},{"label":"Diagnostics","children":["Other","Pre-Anesthetic","Adult Diagnostics","Pre-Anesthetic Diagnostics","Heartworm & Tick Borne Disease Test"]},{"label":"Treatments/Other","children":["Other","Microchip"]}],"datasets":[{"label":"Consumed","backgroundColor":"red","tree":[{"value":0,"children":["0"]},{"value":0,"children":["0"]},{"value":1,"children":["1"]},{"value":0,"children":["0"]},{"value":15,"children":["0","1","3","11","0"]},{"value":15,"children":["2","13"]}]},{"label":"Purchased","backgroundColor":"blue","tree":[{"value":28,"children":["28"]},{"value":1,"children":["1"]},{"value":24,"children":["24"]},{"value":10,"children":["10"]},{"value":103,"children":["2","16","34","49","2"]},{"value":165,"children":["75","90"]}]}]};
            window.onload = () => {
                const ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: data,
                    options: {
                        responsive: true,
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Chart.js Hierarchical Bar Chart'
                        },
                        layout: {
                            padding: {
                                // add more space at the bottom for the hierarchy
                                bottom: 45
                            }
                        },
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                type: 'hierarchical',
                                stacked: false,
                                // offset settings, for centering the categorical
                                //axis in the bar chart case
                                offset: true,

                                // grid line settings
                                gridLines: {
                                    offsetGridLines: true
                                }
                            }],
                            yAxes: [{
                                stacked: false,
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });

            };
```

```css
canvas {
                        -moz-user-select: none;
                        -webkit-user-select: none;
                        -ms-user-select: none;
                    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chartjs-scale-hierarchical"></script>

        <div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
```

for each more column just add another dataset.

Comment: The code snippet results in an error.

Answer (score -2):

This should work as per your requirement http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/chartjs-charts-to-get-you-started/#8-grouped-bar-chart

Comment: I know that grouped bar chart is supported. What I'm looking for is hierarchical categories. Look closely at the category axis in my example chart.